# First Person Controller camera rotation doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I'm looking for some c# script on unity to update first person controller 
camera rotation transform. More specificly, I'm running an animation, and by the end of animation,  I set  "movie camera transform" on fps camera transform, how to show the code. For position variable, everything is ok.  However, rotation variable doesn't work well.
The variable get the transform rotation right (the same movie camera transform), but I can't see the change on scene. The "first person controller rotation transform" 
always get the last rotation coordinate that happened.
I already tested many rotation functions, like Rotate(Vector3), rotation, localRotation, eulerAngles, localEulerAngles....

```
Vector3 pos, roteuler;
public Camera fpscam, movie;

void getPosRot(){
    roteuler = movie.transform.eulerAngles;
    pos = movie.transform.position;
}

void Update(){
    fps.transform.position = pos;
    fps.transform.eulerAngles = roteuler;
}
```

Comment: Try to use `fps.transform.rotation = movie.transform.rotation`?

Comment: doesn't work :/

Comment: Even if you put it in Update? The thing is a Vector3 is stored as a copy, not as a reference. So if your movie cam changes position, it won't be updated.

Comment: I printed (fps.transform.rotation) and printed (movie.transform.rotation) after change. They are equivalent on Update().

Comment: Where do you call `getPosRot()` function?

Comment: On end animation

Answer (score 0):

Here is the camera part of my FPS script:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    float RotateX;
    float RotateY;

    public GameObject Camera;

    public float RotationSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float MaxYAxis = 60.0f;
    public float MinYAxis = -48.0f;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Rotation();
    }

    void Rotation()
    {
        RotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationSpeed;
        RotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationSpeed;
        RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
        Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-RotateY, 0f, 0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);
    }
}
```